# How to add a slash to an input

Tags: python, input, addition

How do you add a slash(/) in front of an input e.g:

```
    a=input('What is your name')
    print(a)
```

it should print with a slash before the name?

Comment: `/` is a (forward) slash, and `-` is a dash.

Comment: do you mean a dash or a slash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append it before the name and print: `print("/"+a)`

Comment: append before is usually called "prepend".

Comment: @IfLoop, Thanks, English is not my natural language :)

Answer (score 0):

Just print a dash* and set the `sep` parameter of [`print`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print) to `''` (to remove the space after it)**:

```
a = input('What is your name')
print('-', a, sep='')
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> a = input('What is your name')
What is your namebob
>>> print('-', a, sep='')
-bob
>>>
```

---

*Note: I used a dash (`-`) in my demonstrations because that is what you said.  However, the same principle applies to a forwardslash (`/`).

**Note: I also assumed that you are on Python 3.x.  If you are on version 2.x though, then you can do this:

```
>>> a = raw_input('What is your name')
What is your namebob
>>> print '-'+a
-bob
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

or just print a dash:

```
print('-{}'.format(a))
```

or just print a dash:

```
print('-%s' % a)
```

or just print a dash (credits to @icodez):

```
print('-', a, sep='')
```

or just print dash (credits to @xndrme):

```
print('-'+a)
```

and the same works with a slash:

```
print('/{}'.format(a))
print('/%s' % a)
print('/', a, sep='')
print('/'+a)
```

;-)

Comment: indeed, it's already in my answer, I just gave all the ways to do it actually